# Access to router directly by typing it's address on the address bar in react-router

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

There is two "main" way to use react-router (V4); The first way is using hash router which you can access directly to an address by typing it on browser's address bar but you must add a # to URL, another way is using BrowserRouter which has a pretty and user-friendly URL structure but you can't directly type the address to render the route.

How I can config HashRouter to work without # or config BrowserRouter to work with directly URL typing, too? Is it possible with .htaccess? How?

---

```
const React = require('react');
const ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
import { HashRouter as Router, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
    
const routes = (
    <Router forceRefresh={false}>
        <div>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Firstpage}/>
            <Route exact path="/projects" component={Projectslist}/>
        </div>
    </Router>
);

ReactDOM.render(routes, document.getElementById('app'));
```

[In this type it works with a # mark. e.g.: localhost:2000/#/projects ]

---

Another type:

```
const React = require('react');
const ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
    
const routes = (
    <Router forceRefresh={true}>
        <div>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Firstpage}/>
            <Route exact path="/projects" component={Projectslist}/>
        </div>
    </Router>
);
    
ReactDOM.render(routes, document.getElementById('app'));
```

[And in this type it works well without a # mark, but it's not possible to load it directly on the browser's address bar.]

Comment: you can display the route by typing the url

Comment: it's exactly whatever I wish to do but it's not working in BrowserRouter :(

Comment: show me your configuration and ill try to see what i can help

Comment: Thanks dear Rei, So check it's code on below.

Comment: are you sure about the second example? or by any chance you are just sending this response to the '/' ? the second example will work perfectly fine, all you need to do is setup the server so it sends the right response on each path.

Comment: Yes, It returns this message on the browser: (e.g. when I wrote http://localhost:2000/projects) Cannot GET /projects

Comment: On a side note, you should use Switch instead of <div> for nesting your routes. `Import { Switch } from 'react-router';` and replace divs with Switch insteda.

Comment: were you able to resolve this? I'm facing the same problem, and historyApiFallback isn't working for me..

Answer (score 4):

If you are using webpack-dev-server, you need to set `historyApiFallback: true` in your config file.

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-historyapifallback