# React does not display the page when typing directly in the address bar or when reloading

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am currently using BrowserRouter, but when I type an address like `/a/:id` directly into the address bar, or reload the page when I am at an address like `/a/:id`, the page goes blank and nothing is displayed.

By using HashRouter, we can avoid a blank white screen, but there will be an obtrusive # in the URL.

How can I get the page to display properly in such a case?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Bar from './Bar'
import A from './A'
import B from './B'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

class Item extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Router>
                    <Bar />
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/a" component={A} />
                        <Route path="/a/:id" component={B} />
                    </Switch>
                </Router>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Item
```

Comment: What are you using to host your website? If you use the webpack devserve there is an option in the config file you should enable, but I guess it depends on the backend you are using

Comment: @Icepickle I use the one automatically generated by create-react-app.

Comment: This problem occurs when running as run server on the local machine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access to router directly by typing it's address on the address bar in react-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43002188/access-to-router-directly-by-typing-its-address-on-the-address-bar-in-react-rou)

Comment: I tried setting historyApiFallback: true, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: You might need to share a bit more concerning your npm scripts, your `webpack.config.js`, how you start it, and what you choose for serverside rendering

Comment: We think that the backend is irrelevant because the same behavior on other pages will display normally. I think it's probably due to React-Router-Dom.

Comment: What are `react-router-dom` and `history` package versions in your `package.json` file?

Comment: The version of react-router-dom is 5.2.0

Comment: I tried to find it, but there was no history package in package.json.

Comment: That's good. I see nothing wrong. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43202453/2873538) should fix the issue. If not, you should consider creating a sandbox or repo with minimal and runnable code to reproduce the issue.